# Getting property of type doesn't exist error when using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm new to TypeScript and trying to understand how to convert my React Hooks code to be typed.  At the moment, I'm getting the following error:

```
Property 'openMenu' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'
Property 'toggle' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'
Property 'slidein' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'
```

This is my code:

```
const Menu: FunctionComponent = ({ openMenu, toggle, slidein }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={`menu ${toggle}`} onClick={openMenu}>
        <div className="bar1"></div>
        <div className="bar2"></div>
        <div className="bar3"></div>
      </div>
      <div className={`expand ${slidein}`}>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/" onClick={openMenu}>
              List
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/add-user" onClick={openMenu}>
              Add User
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>Add Climb</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

The props are being sent in from the parent App.js file, which would normally be fine, but TypeScript doesn't seem to like this.  I've tried adding a type next to each prop, but that doesn't solve the issue either.

**package.json**

```
...
"source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
"ts-loader": "^6.1.2",
"typescript": "^3.6.3",
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FunctionComponent` takes a generic type parameter `P`, which stands for your props type used in `Menu` component. If you don't specify `P`, then `{}` type is used as the default. This common object type does not specify any property types, so `openMenu`, `toggle` and `slidein` will then be unknown to the compiler.

You will want to specify `Menu` like this:

```
// this is just an example. Replace it with your concrete props type
type MenuProps = {
  openMenu(): void;
  toggle: boolean;
  slidein: string;
};

const Menu: FunctionComponent<MenuProps> = ({ openMenu, toggle, slidein }) => {...}
```

Comment: Thanks, still trying to understand it all, but this definitely moved me in the right direction.

Comment: Feel free to ask otherwise. You could write above example also simply as `const Menu = ({ openMenu, toggle, slidein }: MenuProps) => {...}` or `const Menu = (props: MenuProps) => {...}`, the built in `FunctionComponent` is just a React type which add special props types like `children` to the component (if you need them).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to explicitly define the prop types within the function signature, like so:

```
 export const Menu = 

({ openMenu, toggle, slidein }: { 
  openMenu: () => void;
  toggle: boolean;
  slidein: boolean;
}) => {

// rest of your code

}

export default Menu;
```

Better yet, define the type of the props and pass that type definition into the function:

```
type PropTypes = {
  openMenu: () => void;
  toggle: boolean;
  slideIn: boolean;    
}
```

And pass that into the function:

```
const Menu: FunctionComponent<PropTypes> = ({ openMenu, toggle, slideIn 
}) => {
   ...
}
```

Happy coding! ☺️